# How can I select users based on whether or not there are multiple rows for that user?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I recently had an interview question that was worded something like this:

> Select all users from the user table where the user works for multiple businesses and has a salary over 90000 at at least one of the businesses.

Where each row represented a user. Some users had multiple rows (for when they worked for multiple businesses) and each had a businessId.

I'm still pretty new to SQL, I do a lot of basic `select` and `update` statements when writing application code, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Should I be using `count` to find out if there are multiple rows for one user? I'm not sure how to structure it with the `where` clause to check the salary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by the user (for instance the name). Then you can use the `having` clause to do aggregate operations in the group - meaning for every user

```
select username
from users
group by username
having count(distinct businessId) > 1
and max(salary) > 90000
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I was getting screwed up because I assumed I needed a where clause.